# How can I programmatically replace a string on the front page?

Tags: 8

I create a custom module which replaces some string on the front page. For nodes, it work correctly, but it doesn't work on the front page. I wrote this code.

```php
function my_module_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'view.frontpage.page_1') {
    $generateBlock = NULL;
    $block_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
    $block_config = [];
    $block_plugin = $block_manager->createInstance('id_block', $block_config);
    $block_build = $block_plugin->build();
    $block_content = render($block_build);
      
    $block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(4);
    $render = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
    $body = $render['body'][0]['#text'];
    $newContent = str_replace('---*block*---', $block_content, $body);
    // I don't know how render the new modified content from $newContent.
    return $variables;
  }
}
```

I need modify the content with a new string in `$newContent`, but I cannot save this content to variables. My content is not modified.

Comment: Can you tell us your use case? I doubt that doing this in preprocess_page is the best place to do it, but you haven't told us what your goal is.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! There is also no need to render a block in `hook_preprocess_page()`, which is probably the wrong place to do it, since Drupal core already renders blocks of its own. If you need to alter a block, there is a hook for that.

Comment: My use case is - that user create block in administration. This block content is with special string  ---*blok*---  - this string is saying where in block user wish generate content from another block 'id_block'

So I need find this string on front page and replace it with my render block. It work correctly in preprocess_node, but not in preprocess_page because I cannot save content - this not work $variables['page']['content']['kontakt'] = $mynewcontent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the [Custom Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_tokens) and [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) modules together?

There's also this brief tutorial on implementing your own custom tokens:
https://codimth.com/blog/web/drupal/how-create-custom-token-drupal-8-9

And here is Token Filter's Readme:
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/token_filter/-/blob/8.x-1.x/README.txt

Comment: Thanks. Custom token was good solution. I created it, and now is much better than before :)